# Cómo ejecutar software (OptumG2) via Python

Tags: python, cmd

necesito ayuda!

Estoy trabajando en mi tesis y soy nuevo en programación. Necesito modelar muchos casos en el software OptumG2, para lo cual creo y modifico sus archivos de extensión .g2x (del tipo xml). Estoy trabajando en Jupyter Notebook desde Anaconda3.

Mi problema es que al usar subprocess.run() no encuentra el archivo, aún siguiendo las indicaciones del manual Command Line Version del programa.

Pensaba en definir una función con subprocess y que su argumento sea el comando en la cmd del programa para su ejecución, pero no estoy seguro si es posible lo segundo. Les dejo lo que he intentado.

Desde ya, muchas gracias.

```py
import subprocess 
subprocess.run(['C:\\Users\\matia\\OneDrive - Universidad Católica de la Santísima Concepción\\Escritorio\\Tesis\\Pruebas Plantilla.g2x'])
```

Comment: Probaste escribir en vez de Escritorio, Desktop en el path? Es decir, que te quede `'C:\\Users\\matia\\OneDrive - Universidad Católica de la Santísima Concepción\\Desktop\\Tesis\\Pruebas Plantilla.g2x'`

Comment: Si yo accedo a mi escritorio desde el explorador de windows, el escritorio está referido con el nombre Desktop, no Escritorio.

Comment: Acabo de probar y sigue sin funcionar

Comment: Revisaste que hayas escrito bien el path del archivo? Tu nombre de usuario realmente es matia? No es matias? La extension del archivo es la correcta? Hay alguna tilde de mas o menos?

Comment: Si es ese, no recuerdo por qué quedo así. Tenía otro pc donde escribí matia en vez de matias y en el de ahora usé el mismo correo. Nunca supe como modificarlo.

Comment: Por lo demás que mencionas, entonces es posible realizar lo que consulto? Con eso ya puedo buscar el error con más certeza de que se puede solucionar.

Comment: Para serte sincero, no se nada sobre el tema del que hablas, pero como dices que no encuentra el archivo, es posible que el problema sea un directorio mal escrito. Y de eso si se. Perdona, pero más que decirte que revises bien el path no hay nada más que pueda decirte...

Comment: No te preocupes, todo tipo de ayuda me sirve. Agradecido!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu error es que no pasas un ejecutable.

El primer argumento debe ser el ejecutable que vas a ejecutar (lógico), después vienen los argumentos.

Por ejemplo, si quiero cargar mi editor de texto `xed` con un archivo `variables.txt`, ejecuto:

```
subprocess.run(["/usr/bin/xed", "variables.txt"])
```

Tienes que pasar la ruta completa del ejecutable.